# Inserting data into preformed dom elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a pretty javascript heavy web page and was wondering if there was a neater way of composing html elements that will be inserted in the dom. At the moment I'm doing something like:

```
var some_div = "<div class='yaba daba doo' "
some_div += "data-foo='" + some_handy_variable + "'>" + some_html_content + "</div>";
```

This should render as:

```
<div class='yaba daba doo' data-foo='some handy id'>html content</div>
```

But the process of getting there is not that easy to parse :( Is there a way to pre-form the div i.e.

```
var some_div = "<div class='yaba daba doo' data-foo=''></div>"
```

then somehow insert the data/variables to then have the some_div variable render as

```
<div class='yaba daba doo' data-foo='some handy id'>html content</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do:

```
var some_div = $("<div class='yaba daba doo'></div>") // create the div and store in variable
some_div.attr("data-foo", "some handy id"); // add attribute
some_div.html("html content") // set html
```

And you can use any other jquery methods for the dynamic div

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a templating framework such as [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)? It will probably help you with tidying up the JS code you're mentioning. You'd have objects such as:

```
var o = { Class: 'yaba daba doo', Data-Foo: 'Some handy id', html: 'Something here' }
```

And a `myTemplate` that would look like:

```
<div class='{{Class}}' data-foo='{{Data-Foo}}'>{{html}}</div>
```

Then, you can use that template to populate with whatever data you need.

```
var template = Handlebars.Compile(myTemplate);
var myResult = template(o);
```

I know it's not exactly what you had asked for, but just trying to offer up a solution that might help you keep everything cleaner and more scalable. :) Give it some thought!

Comment: I do need to start looking into js templating at some point - thank you for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Do you like something like this better? You could also add the classes in the same way.

```
$("<div class='yaba daba doo'>")
  .prop("data-foo", "some handy id")
  .html("html content")
```

Or like this:

```
$("body").append(
  $("<div class='yaba daba doo' data-foo='some handy id'>html content</div>")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I find this pretty easy for attaching properties using jQuery

```
 $("<div>", {
  id: "someDiv",
  css: {
     height: "50px",
     width: "50px"
  }
}.appendTo("body")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use JavaScript way of creating DOM elements like:

```
<code>
var divEle = document.createElement("div");
divEle.class    = "yaba daba doo";
divEle.data-foo = "some handy id";
</code>
```

After this, add the element as child element of any other DOM element.

```
<code>
document.body.appendChild(divEle);
</code>
```